# how to validate date in report builder 3.0

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have `startDate` and `endDate` parameter in my report. I need to validate them with 2 conditions. Below validation code(that not working):

```
=IIF((Parameters!EndDate.Value < Parameters!StartDate.Value) 
    AND (Parameters!EndDate.Value > 
      DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1 , Parameters!StartDate.Value)),
  "Error", "")
```

Here first condition only works, second not working. I create `TextBox` and write it in `value` expression. What I do wrong?